# Is there a way to make a two-sided inner shadow in a div?

Tags: html, css

Is there any possible way to make a two-sided inner shadow by shadow-box in css like the image below?

[image]

Comment: You can use an image

Comment: The width of `div` is 100%. So, is is better not to use an image.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a background image to fill the div:

[image]

```css
#custom{
  min-width: 200px;
  min-height:200px;
  width : 100%;
  background-image : url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6HMs.png");
  background-repeat : no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<div id="custom">
  
</div>
```

And make sure to give it `background-size: contain;` so the image can fit all the div.

**EDIT:**

This is a snippet using a border in the div, so you can see that the image is filling all the space.

```css
#custom {
  min-width: 200px;
  min-height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6HMs.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="custom">

</div>
```

Comment: -Thank you. How can I centralize the background image?

Comment: @user2326844 I edited the code use `background-size: contain;`, to make it fit the content.

Comment: Why making an additional http request to do something that can be done with CSS alone?

Comment: @JoseRuiSantos, because pseudo elements, don't have full support in FF and IE browsers.

Comment: @chsdk That's not true, as you can see [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gencontent)

Comment: @chsdk, but `background-size: contain;` does not centralize it. The image is sticking to the left side of the `div`

Comment: @JoseRuiSantos I referred to [**this link**](https://css-tricks.com/browser-support-pseudo-elements/).

Comment: @user2326844, take a look at my EDIT I used a border to show you that the image is filling the whole div.

Comment: @chsdk That's a 2011 post. IE7 and below will not display those shadows and will not be the end of the world because of that. We are talking about a minor cosmetic stuff that less than 1% of the users will not see... and they will not even know what they are missing out.

Comment: @JoseRuiSantos Fair enough, you are right. Another point is that with a background image you can totally control the shadow effec, it will be easier.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pseudo elements for both shadows:

```css
div {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 2em -.5em gray;
  line-height: 3em;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div:before,
div:after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 5%;
  top: -100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2em #aaa;
}

div:after {
  left: auto;
  right: 5%;
}

div[contenteditable] {
  margin-top: 3em;
  display: inline-block;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div>hello world</div>
<div contenteditable>TYPE HERE...and watch the shadows</div>
```

These shadows have a responsive behavior. Their size expands when the `div` width expands.